# Can I use my USB space again after burning an iso file in it?

Tags: windows-10, usb, formatting, iso-image

I will "burn" Windows 10 on my 16GB USB, but I am afraid to burn it because the process is maybe irreversable... Can I format the USB (not quick format) so I can use my USB as I normally would?

Comment: Yes you can format and burn again there will not be any problem.

Comment: Change the word "burn" in your question to "save", and you will have the answer. We only use the word "Burn" in relation to CDs and DVDs because the laser physically changes the disk. Every other media, we talk about "saving".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, yes you can re format your USB since its not like CD's or DVD's that close the session and writes data permanently on it .

Comment: The whole process is different. Entirely.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher not really...

Comment: "The most common form of recordable optical media is write-once organic dye technology, popularized in the form of the CD-R and still used for higher-capacity media such as DVD-R." - that *is* different from writing to a USB storage device.

Answer (score -2):

Just download rufus [rufus home page](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

it helps to format a disk to bootable and if you have the bootable unticked it will remove the disk from being bootable. 
I use it all the time as its easy to add new OS to it and format it again to use as a normal USB.

Comment: The question was simply whether burning an ISO is permanent vs. the drive could be reformatted.  Rufus is sort of irrelevant to the question.

Comment: True that. Was just showing what I use and its never an issue.